# Is it better to parse an integer in a timer or save it globally?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, timer

Ok so I have a small Website, that displays a number or values linked to a phone routing system.

This website has an "update" function that's called regularly based on a timer with an interval ranging from 1 to 10 seconds, determined when the website is loaded.

Considering, that I want to minimize resources devoted to this website, is it better to save this integer globally or pass it through the timer callback 
;)?

I do realize that the impact is probably minimal, but this has been bothering me ;).

Comment: Unluckily jsperfs is currently offline: https://jsperf.com/ else it could've been a good source you could use to try what is the difference. ;). In any case, as long as you don't call that function **very frequently**, I don't think it would have a great impact on the performance at all.

Comment: Good advice from @briosheje . In the case of calling `parseInt` I would go as far as to say *very frequently* would need to be up in the thousands/sec. Which hopefully isn't the case. Don't bother with performance-based micro-optimizations like this. Just do what makes your code easier to read & write

Comment: hehe this is just one of those things my mind keeps coming back to.

Comment: Also, if you really bother about memory consumption and so on you could just think about using a javascript code minifier, like uglifyjs: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS . If there is any possible way to minify your code uglifyjs will do that for you ;)

Comment: that's allready happening :D

Comment: Then don't bother, as long as you are not a machine or not that experienced with javascript you're probably not going to be able to save more than that, if you just want to feel satisfied or whatever, try jsperfs when it will be online again, you will find by yourself, in any case, that as long as the call is not that frequent (and as RGraham pointed out it should be **very** frequent) you probably won't see any difference at all.